# jquery - syntax for including a jquery object as a text or html property

Tags: jquery, appendto

I am not sure what is the correct way of writing the code, or is it even a possible jquery format.

I have

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
  var inner = $('<div/>', {text: 'it works'});
  var x = ' xyz ';

  var row = $('<div/>', {
    id: 'foo',
    'class': 'abc',
    html: 'test'+ x + inner.text(),
    css: {'padding-left': '5px'}
  });

  row.appendTo('body');
}
```

The output is test xyz [object Object]

What is the correct syntax for displaying the inner variable so that the correct output would be 'test xyz it works' ?

I know that it would work with using `inner.appendTo(row)`

A secondary question: If I could get the code to work, what would be faster?  appendTo or defining the html with a variable.

TIA

Comment: Try `html: 'test' + x + inner.html()` or `html: 'test' + x + inner.text()`. This is a total shot in the dark, just fyi. :)

Comment: Awesome, I'll post it as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: Follow up 'answer' for my secondary question -->  apparently, if I use html: inner.html() , it will append only the html contents of the 'inner' div, it will ignore inner's css definitions.  I am not sure which is faster, but it seems like this method will require specific declarations of all the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want `html: 'test' + x + inner.html();` or `html: 'test' + x + inner.text();`

Comment: Thanks Elliot, by any chance that you know if this method is faster than the append method?

Comment: Elliot, take a look at my follow up comment.

Comment: Hi Josh, I don't quite follow the test results.  The chart shows that Elliot's method has more ops/sec (higher is better). But the table above that says that Elliot's method is SLOWER.  I don't know if the code for that tool is reversed or that I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want to move the inner `div` into the containing (`row`) div? If so, you'd want to do the following:

```
$(function() {
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var inner = $('<div/>', {
    text: 'it works'
    });

    var x = ' xyz ';

    var row = $('<div/>', {
    id: 'foo',
    'class': 'abc',
    html: 'test'+ x,
    css: {  
    'padding-left': '5px'
        }
    }).append(inner).appendTo('body');

    }//end for
});
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, see Elliot's answer.  Your append method works too, I was just wonder how I could to it the other way.  BTW, do you know if append is faster for jquery to execute than Elliot's method?